# Python and SQL Server - How to select in multiple columns with variable?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-3.x

I am trying to select with SQL Server in multiple columns with a Value from the GUI which is a user input.

My select looks like this at the moment:

```
test = self.ms.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE Status = 'Deleted' AND TestID LIKE ? OR Name LIKE ?", ("%{}%".format(self.search_entry.GetValue(),"%{}%".format(self.search_entry.GetValue())))
```

My Problem is that ID is an Integer in my DB and Name is a String.

What is the best way to search with a User Input variable inside multiple columns which could contain INT or VARCHAR Values?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
test = self.ms.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE Status = 'Deleted' AND TestID=%d OR Name=%s", ("%{}%".format(self.search_entry.GetValue(),"%{}%".format(self.search_entry.GetValue())))
```